# Don't fully understand recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm doing the interview prep exercises for Hack Reactor. One of the assignments is to write a function that can multiply two numbers without using the multiplication operator. I was able to but the code was very long and clunky, I found a much better solution on github:

```
var output = multiply(4, 7);

function multiply(num1, num2) {
  if(num2 === 0) { 
    return 0;
  }
  if(num2 > 0 ) {    
    return (num1 + multiply(num1, num2-1));
  }
  if(num2 < 0 ) {
    return -multiply(num1, -num2);
  }
}  


console.log(output);
```

I don't fully understand how this code works. I know it's recursive and handles 3 different cases. When both inputs are positive the function adds a recursive call of itself to num1 with the first input staying the same while subtracting 1 from the second input. This makes sense but what I don't get is that eventually num2 reaches 0 yet the function doesn't return 0. I can see this by adding a console.log statement in the first line of the function, so how does that work?
Also I can't figure out how to add a console.log that tracks the return value of the function as it calls itself over and over again. I imagine it would look something like:

```
4
4 + multiply(num1, num2-1)
8 + multiply(num1, num2-1)
12 + multiply(num1, num2-1)
```

But I cant get it to work. Thank you! And the problem number is module 1 exercise 141 'multiply'
Appreciate any and all help!

Comment: `write a function that can multiply two numbers` you mean two integers? That's certainly a lot easier than two doubles, which is the type used by JavaScript `Number`.

Comment: That's a very ugly function. Back to your question: in your last code block (which is not a code!), you have to keep subtracting the original `num2`... so, it will be: `4... 4 + multiply(num1, num2-1)... 8 + multiply(num1, num2-2)...12 + multiply(num1, num2-3)` So, in short, what this function does is `4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4`, that is, it adds `num1` to itself `num2` times.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am getting the question right. But you don't need to understand what is going on inside recursion.

```
if(num2 === 0) { 
    return 0;
  }
```

This is your base case. So if you call `var output = multiply(4, 0);` it will return 0.

This is how you say a recursive function to stop.

Visually it should be something like:

> 4 + multiply(4,6) + 4 + multiply(4,5) + 4 + multiply(4,4) + 4 + multiply(4,3) + 4 + multiply(4,2) + 4 + multiply(4,1) + 4 + 0 (your base case)

So you are left with: 4+4+4+4+4+4+4 = 28

I believe the easiest way to understand it will be to look at arguments. Your num1 is the number you keep adding up. Your num2 is the number of times you add num1 up. This is your counter in descending order until you reach your base case of 0.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: Thank you for your response,
What I'm mainly confused about is that because 1 is being subtracted from num2 on each recursion eventually it will reach 0. When this happens; the function is set to return 0. Doesn't the return statement save whatever is being returned to the function? I figured that because it's set to return 0 and will eventually always do so that the function should spit out 0. Clearly that's not the case but I'm unsure as to why that is.

Comment: The answer by Tom Bryant is the classic representation of a recursion logic. Probably easier to understand than mine. Yes, it does return zero and it is exactly what you need. You want your recursion to drill down until it hits 0. Once it happens, the function will bounce back. So, if you look at the Tom's answer - nothing technically happens until you hit 0. After that, you go back adding your num1 until you hit the original num2 number. I hope this will help. Or maybe this video will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttTH_WX-Cbo

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's going to work below, it keeps going until num2 = 0 in which case it returns 0.

multiply(4, 7)

4 + multiply(4, 6)

4 + multiply(4, 5)

4 + multiply(4, 4)

4 + multiply(4, 3)

4 + multiply(4, 2)

4 + multiply(4, 1)

4 + multiply(4, 0)

**So 4 + multiply(4, 0) will = 4.**

4 + multiply(4, 1) will = 8. Keep going back up and eventually we have:

multiply(4, 7)=28

4 + multiply(4, 6)=24

4 + multiply(4, 5)=20

4 + multiply(4, 4)=16

4 + multiply(4, 3)=12

4 + multiply(4, 2)=8

4 + multiply(4, 1)=4

4 + multiply(4, 0)=0

Answer (score 0):

The code functions recursively. For example, we will determine

```
multiply(4,3)
```

What makes it recursive is that the first thing it actually calculates is 
`multiply(4,0)` which returns `4`.
Once this is determined, the following can then be determined in sequence

```
multiply(4,1)

multiply(4,2)
```

You cannot get a return value of multiply(4,3) solely by itself. If you take out the 1st and 3rd if statements it shouldn't return anything.

Answer (score -3):

Actually you should know there are much easier ways to do so.

You can represent a multiplication easy by a sum.

So that means 4*3 = 3+3+3+3

So this in remind, you can build this:

```
function mul(x,y)
{
    var sum=0,lim = Math.abs(x);
    for(var i=0; i<lim; i++)
    {
        sum += y;
    }
    return (x<0)?-sum:sum;
}
```

Comment: The question is about understanding the given function, not coming up with an easier method.

Comment: Then you should read the beginng of his question too.
He said, he can't find an easier method and he couldn't write one. I just wanted to explain some simple stuff to him...

Comment: I think you should re-read it. Nowhere does it say he wasn't able to find an easier method, nor was he looking for one. All it says is that this approach is "better" than his original attempted solution.

Comment: That function can't handle negative inputs so its not really a better solution

Comment: Sure it can handle negative solutions -.-

Comment: I just tried it with negative inputs and it always returns a positive integer